# changing an instance of a class changes entire class

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, dictionary

```
class class1():
    def __init__(self,dict1={1:2,3:4}):
        self.dict1=dict1
        return

list1=[]
list1.append(class1())
list1.append(class1())
list1.append(class1())
list1[0].dict1[1]="test"
print(list1[0].dict1,list1[1].dict1,list1[2].dict1)
```

Output:
{1: 'test', 3: 4} {1: 'test', 3: 4} {1: 'test', 3: 4}

Whenever I change an element of the first term of "list1", say the value of key "1" from "2" to "test", every element adopts that same change.

How do I make it so that only the first element gets altered?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `def __init__(self,dict1=None): if not dict1: self.dict1=dict1 or {1:2,3:4}`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
class class1():
    def __init__(self,dict1={1:2,3:4}):
        self.dict1=dict1.copy()
        return
```